# Chapters inside LoF and LoT?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

I was wondering if it was possible to section the LoF (and similarly LoT) by Parts and/or Chapters.

Currently, I have :

> List of Figures
>
> 1.1 blablabla
>
> 1.2 blablabla
>
> 1.3 blablabla
>
> 2.1 blablabla
>
> 2.2 blablabla
>
> 1.1 blablabla
>
> 1.2 blablabla

And I'd like to obtain :

> **Part 1**
>
> *Chapter 1*
>
> 1.1 blablabla
>
> 1.2 blablabla
>
> 1.3 blablabla
>
> *Chapter 2*
>
> 2.1 blablabla
>
> 2.2 blablabla
>
> **Part 2**
>
> *Chapter 1*
>
> 1.1 blablabla
>
> 1.2 blablabla

---

Comment: Are you using any special class?

Comment: You would need to add `\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{#1}` and `\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{#1}` for every `\chapter` (`#1` is the chapter title), either manually or by patching `\chapter`. However, I guess there is already a read-made solution available somewhere, so I wait before posting such code.

Comment: If you are using a KOMA-Class you can use the option `listof=chapterentry` for chapters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can insert part, chapter or any other references in a table of contents, list of figures or list of tables with `\addcontentsline{ext}{type}{text}` where `ext` is the extension of auxiliar file (usually toc, lof, lot), `type` specifies type of contents and `text` what you want to be shown in the list. Here you have a simple example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\part{A}
\addcontentsline{lof}{part}{Part A}
\chapter{A1}
\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{Chapter A1}
\section{A11}
\begin{figure}
\caption{FigA1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{FigA2}
\end{figure}
\chapter{A2}
\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{Chapter A2}
\begin{figure}
\caption{FigA21}
\end{figure}
\part{B}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

The package [tocloft](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/) allows you to define or change the format of a table of contents but I've never used it. You can read its introduction and will learn how ToC works in LaTeX.

EDIT: You can avoid typing twice chapter names and part names if you declare your own commands. Look at the example `\mypart` command contains `\part` and `\addcontentsline`. This way, parts and chapters in `lof` will look the same as in `toc`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{%
\part{#1}
\addcontentsline{lof}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}
}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
\chapter{#1}
\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\mypart{A}
\mychapter{A1}
\section{A11}
\begin{figure}
\caption{FigA1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{FigA2}
\end{figure}
\mychapter{A2}
\begin{figure}
\caption{FigA21}
\end{figure}
\mypart{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect ! Is it possible to have them Chapter or Parts numbered (as in the ToC ?)

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: With `\mypart` and `\mychapter`, the optional argument of `\part` and `\chapter` cannot be used.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I know it. I've also read somewhere about problems with `hyperref` and `addcontentsline` which probably persist with my partial solution. I've never used a `lof` or `lot` and any package to configure them so I hope somebody else will provide us with a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

In order to add automatically the entries to the list of figures, you can patch the relevant commands:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
   \addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
   \addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@part}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
   \addcontentsline{lof}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
   \addcontentsline{lot}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
\makeatother
```

However this will print the lines also when there are no figures or tables in the chapter.

Generally speaking, I'd not recommend such detailed listings, as the figure or table numbers already say where they belong.