# Include Appendix as a Chapter in LOF and LOT, and chapters formatting in both lof and lot

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titletoc

I'm doing my thesis and I need a better display of the chapters that are shown on LoT and LoF, as well as I want to include the `\appendix` as a Chapter to LoT and LoF (notice that `\appendixname` is "Anexo" in the LoT picture below).

I read an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32758/89204) which recommends to use: `\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{Anexo}`, and it adds perfectly the "Anexo" chapter to LoT & LoF. The thing is that, as you can see on the image below, the "Anexo" is with hyperlink and with the page number also (in other color). The point is that it looks bad comparing to the other chapters style. I'd like all to look the same, with a bigger font size if possible `:-)`. In order to add the chapters as it is shown for all chapters (not counting "Anexo", i.e II. Estado del Arte and III. Métodos y materiales), I used an answer suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52747/89204).

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
   \captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

    \makeatletter 
    % initial definitions of the chapter info (name and number)
    \def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
    \newtoggle{noFigs}

    \apptocmd{\@chapter}%
    {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
        \global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}

    % the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, 
    % it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
            \iftoggle{noFigs}{
                \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
                    {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
                \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
            }{}
        }%
    }

    \makeatother


    \makeatletter 
    \def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
    \newtoggle{noTabs}

    \apptocmd{\@chapter}%
    {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
        \global\toggletrue{noTabs}}{}{}

    % the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, 
    % it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
            \iftoggle{noTabs}{
                \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
                    {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
                \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
            }{}
        }%
    }
    \makeatother

\addto\captionsspanish{
\def\tablename{Tabla}
\def\listtablename{\'Indice de tablas}
}


\usepackage[margin=25mm,inner=30mm]{geometry}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor=blue]{hyperref}


\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} 

\makeatletter
\def\tableofcontents{%
 \newpage
 \centerline{\Large\scshape Índice General} 
 \vspace*{0.3in}
 \@mkboth{Contenidos}{}
 \@starttoc{toc}
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\listoftables{%
 \newpage
 \centerline{\Large\scshape Índice de Tablas} 
 \vspace*{0.3in}
 \@mkboth{Contenidos}{}
 \@starttoc{lot}
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\listoffigures{%
 \newpage
 \centerline{\Large\scshape Índice de Figuras} 
 \vspace*{0.3in}
 \@mkboth{Contenidos}{}
 \@starttoc{lof}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{spanish}

%------------------------- TOC.

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice General}

%------------------------- LOF.

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}

%------------------------- LOT.

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}

\clearpage
\chapter{Capítulo 1}
% There are no tables here...

\clearpage
\chapter{Estado del Arte}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Grupos de códigos de área.}\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
   \toprule
   hola & chao\\
   \midrule
   bla & blabla\\
   alb & albalb\\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%and many other tables...
\clearpage
\chapter{Métodos y materiales}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{CARACTERÍSTICAS TÉCNICAS DEL ESPECTRÓMETRO STS-NIR }} \\
    \midrule
    Fabricante & OceanOptics \\
    bla & blabla\\
    \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}%
   \caption{Características del espectrómetro y de la fibra óptica.}\label{tab:car_espectrometro}%
\end{table}

% Here's much more... (bla bla... + bibliography...)
% And at the end (the appendix):

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexo}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexo}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\appendix       
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{Anexo} %This is the first approach.
\clearpage
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage

\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}


\refstepcounter{section}% 
\section*{\thesection. \quad Características generales de las agujas y conos de pino.}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        & bla & blabla \\
        \midrule
        Moisture (wt.\%) & 12     & 8,9 \\
        bla bla          & bla    & bla \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \caption{Características generales de agujas y conos de pino.}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

It is very possible that I'm missing something (I'm trying to put just what I think It's necessary, because I've got hundreds of code lines in my preamble), therefore I'll be very alert for any question and/or answer. So, to conclude, the things that I'm asking to solve are:

1. That `\appendix` chapter ("Anexo" in LoT) has the same style as
   the other chapters (i.e Estado del Arte and Métodos y materiales).
2. To modify the chapters style in both LoT and LoF (to change the
   font size, color...with that it's perfect!).

I'd really appreciate some help!

[image: on the image below]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE). The code you provided is far too long to be minimal and has missing packages, so it's not working. A MWE should have only the necessary packages, be compilible and have enough code to show the issue. Providing a MWE will definetely increase your chances of getting help as it makes the helpers lives much easier! `:D`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos, I already modified the code to run perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `hyperref` anchor line on your definition of `\apptocmd{\@chapter}`, done by:

```
\global\let\thischapterHref\@currentHref
```

Replace your definition by this:

```
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{%
    \gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}%
    \gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\let\thischapterHref\@currentHref % hyperref
    \global\toggletrue{noFigs}%
    \global\toggletrue{noTabss}%
}{}{}
```

And you also have to call the anchor when making the list:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
        \iftoggle{noTabs}{
            \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}%
                {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}%
                {}%
                {\thischapterHref}% << for hyperlink
                }
            \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
        }{}
    }%
}
```

Furthermore, to [supress the page number on ToC entries added with `\addtocontents`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194733/114143) instead of the `\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{Anexo}` you should use the below code, where the last argument `chapter\thepage` refers to `hyperref`'s link anchor:

```
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Anexo}{}{chapter\thepage}}
```

The complete (M)WE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter 
% initial definitions of the chapter info (name and number)
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}
\newtoggle{noTabs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}{%
    \gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}%
    \gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\let\thischapterHref\@currentHref % hyperref
    \global\toggletrue{noFigs}%
    \global\toggletrue{noTabs}%
}{}{}


% the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, 
% it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
        \iftoggle{noFigs}{
            \addtocontents{lof}{%
                \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
                {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{\thischapterHref} }
            \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
        }{}
    }%
}

% the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, 
% it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
        \iftoggle{noTabs}{
            \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
                {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{\thischapterHref} }
            \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
        }{}
    }%
}
\makeatother

\addto\captionsspanish{
    \def\tablename{Tabla}
    \def\listtablename{\'Indice de tablas}
}


\usepackage[margin=25mm,inner=30mm]{geometry}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} 

\makeatletter
\def\tableofcontents{%
    \newpage
    \centerline{\Large\scshape Índice General} 
    \vspace*{0.3in}
    \@mkboth{Contenidos}{}
    \@starttoc{toc}
}

\def\listoftables{%
    \newpage
    \centerline{\Large\scshape Índice de Tablas} 
    \vspace*{0.3in}
    \@mkboth{Contenidos}{}
    \@starttoc{lot}
}

\def\listoffigures{%
    \newpage
    \centerline{\Large\scshape Índice de Figuras} 
    \vspace*{0.3in}
    \@mkboth{Contenidos}{}
    \@starttoc{lof}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{spanish}

    %------------------------- TOC.

    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice General}

    %------------------------- LOF.

    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}

    %------------------------- LOT.

    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}

    \clearpage
    \chapter{Capítulo 1}
    % There are no tables here...

    \clearpage
    \chapter{Estado del Arte}

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{Grupos de códigos de área.}\label{tab:1}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \toprule
            hola & chao\\
            \midrule
            bla & blabla\\
            alb & albalb\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    %and many other tables...
    \clearpage
    \chapter{Métodos y materiales}

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lc}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{CARACTERÍSTICAS TÉCNICAS DEL ESPECTRÓMETRO STS-NIR }} \\
            \midrule
            Fabricante & OceanOptics \\
            bla & blabla\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
        \caption{Características del espectrómetro y de la fibra óptica.}\label{tab:car_espectrometro}%
    \end{table}

    % Here's much more... (bla bla... + bibliography...)
    % And at the end (the appendix):

    \clearpage
    \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
    \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexo}
    \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexo}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

    \appendix       
    \phantomsection
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Anexo}{}{chapter\thepage}}
    \clearpage
    \addappheadtotoc
    \appendixpage

    \counterwithin{table}{section}
    \counterwithin{figure}{section}
    \counterwithin{equation}{section}


    \refstepcounter{section}% 
    \section*{\thesection. \quad Características generales de las agujas y conos de pino.}

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcc}
            \toprule
            & bla & blabla \\
            \midrule
            Moisture (wt.\%) & 12     & 8,9 \\
            bla bla          & bla    & bla \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
        \caption{Características generales de agujas y conos de pino.}
    \end{table}%

\end{document}
```

In result you have all your chapters as hyperlinks:

[image: compilation result]

Comment: You actually changed the color (because of hyperlink), what it's only missing would be to take the page number of "Anexo" (\appendix) of LoT and LoF so it can be shown just as the other chapters. Do you know how to do it? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @JorgeV, you're welcome, don't forget to upvote helpful questions and answers as well as accepting correct answers. See edited answer above, I think everything is clear now! `:D`

Comment: Amazing! Works great, thank you very much :D!!!

Comment: @Guilherme_Zanotelli I found a little problem in the code. When I add another chapter (call it chapter "x"), the title of it ("x") goes inside of "Anexo" in LoT. I tried a lot in order to find out why, and the result was because there was no table in chapter ("x"). Do you know what should I modify in order to change that? I mean, I don't have tables in all my chapters, and if I do not add one, the problem will remain. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry @JorgeV, but I don't understant the problem you're stating. You're supposed to be using `\section` not `\chapter`. Also, if you undo the changes I proposed and the problem persists, than it's unrelated to this question. Can you please check that? And if the problem is being caused by the proposed solution, add a new MWE showing it, if not, please ask a new question then! `:)`

Comment: Guilherme, sorry if I was not clear. The thing is that I added a new chapter to my thesis. Then, I compiled latex and I found out that in LoT the "Anexo" chapter got a mistaken "Section" which was called as the new chapter I did. I was trying to figure out what was going on, so then I realized I had no table environments in that new chapter, I did a table and problem solved. The thing is that the new chapter I made was entering wrong to LoT because it was staying inside the "Anexo" chapter. I think there is something that is forcing the (...red the other comment)

Comment: command you made (for adding the "Anexo" chapter tables to LoT), I mean, the code forces me to put a table environment in all chapters, If I don't do that, then I'll get the mistake I'm telling you, which is the chapter with no tables at all inside the LoT (and more specific, inside the "Anexo" chapters, as if it was a table at "Anexo"). I know its kind of difficult to understand, and It would be better if I can send you a picture with the problem. Is it possible? Sorry for bothering so much, I really appreciate your time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's ok, we're to help @JorgeV. The thing is: I truly believe that the changes I proposed are not the culprit here (because I only added `hyperref` anchors to your code, nothing else). Therefore I think you should restore to your original preamble and recompile, of course the lines won't be blue anymore, but I think the problem you're experiencing will persist. If so, we can conclude that this is a differente issue (therefore, different question). In the event I'm wrong my code is the cause, we'll work it out here. Is that ok?  Can you do that please? `:D`