# List of Tables and List of Figures error when using \caption

Tags: table-of-contents

I came across this problem when I tried to write my dissertation.

Figures were not showing in contents: List of Figures. Neither were the tables. When I tried to compile with `\caption{some figure}` added, I had an error message.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\l@figure #1#2->\ifnum \c@lofdepth 
                                   >\z@ \vskip \cftbeforefigskip {\leftskip ...
l.2 ...paces normal \relax }}{3}{figure.caption.6}
                                                  %
?
```

I tried and found a helpful question that was answered by others. [Include Appendix as a Chapter in LOF and LOT, and chapters formatting in both lof and lot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338096/include-appendix-as-a-chapter-in-lof-and-lot-and-chapters-formatting-in-both-lo)

So I loaded the code before `\begin{document}`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\thisparttitle{}\def\thispartnumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}

\apptocmd{\@part}%
  {\gdef\thisparttitle{#1}\gdef\thispartnumber{\thepart}%
    \global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \iftoggle{noFigs}{
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {part}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thispartnumber} {\thisparttitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
    }{}
  }%
}

\makeatother
```

However, after loading the helpful setting code into my code before `\begin{document}`. I found the package `subcaption` was not compatible. The `subfigure` package can be an alternative, but its not as good. Additionally, I found the `\floatfoot` command also produced an error message after I compiled with setting code.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you need the code that you copied?

Comment: @Werner I edited my question and add the error message. My goal is to load the subcaption package meanwhile preambled the code I copied. I use the codes as I got the error message I posted when trying to add figure/table captions.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I Just found a solution to the question that I posted.

**Copy the following code into the preamble:**

```
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list=false}

\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

\newcounter{lofdepth}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}
```