# Add part title in KOMA-Script LoF/LoT

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, koma-script

As specified in *§3.20. Floating Environments of Tables and Figures* on page 128 sq. of [KOMA-Script documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), one can add the option `listof=withchapterentry` to

> Marks chapter starts at the lists of floating environments by a copy of their entries to the table of contents.

I.e. it adds chapter title above figures belonging to this chapter:

```
List of Figure

Chapter 1
  1.1  My first figure.......................13
  1.2  My second figure......................17

Chapter 42
  42.1 My last figure.......................210
```

---

**Question:** As I use the `scrbook` class, what I'd like to do, is to emulate the same behavior yet with part titles, instead of chapter ones. I.e. to kind of create the `listof=withpartentry` option.
 
(I only need to make part titles appear, not chapter ones)

How could I do this?

---

Some questions already deal with this issue (e.g., [Chapters inside LoF and LoT?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32755/64454), [Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52746/64454)). However, they are intended for standard classes (`book`). I think 'dirty' workarounds could be avoided with the `scrbook` class since the feature is already implemented for chapters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could patch `\addparttocentry` to get an entry for each part in LOF and LOT:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\unsettoc{lof}{chapteratlist}% remove the chapter gap in LOF
\unsettoc{lot}{chapteratlist}% % remove the chapter gap in LOT

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\addparttocentry{%
  \addxcontentsline{lof}{part}[{#1}]{#2}% copy the part entry to LOF
  \addxcontentsline{lot}{part}[{#1}]{#2}% copy the part entry to LOT
}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\part{Part One}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\captionof{figure}{My first figure}
\captionof{figure}{My second figure}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\captionof{figure}{A figure in Chapter Two}
\part{Part Two}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\captionof{figure}{My next figure}
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\addpart{Unnumbered Part}
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\captionof{figure}{My last figure}
\end{document}
```

Or in all lists controlled by package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass[listof=ignorechapter]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\addparttocentry{%
  \doforeachtocfile{%
    \ifstr{\@currext}{toc}{}{%
      \addxcontentsline{\@currext}{part}[{#1}]{#2}%
    }%
  }%
}{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\part{Part One}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\captionof{figure}{My first figure}
\captionof{figure}{My second figure}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\captionof{figure}{A figure in Chapter Two}
\part{Part Two}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\captionof{figure}{My next figure}
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\addpart{Unnumbered Part}
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\captionof{figure}{My last figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

It is also possible to declare a new style for the part entries in the lists. Example without page numbers for the part entries:

```
\documentclass[listof=ignorechapter]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\addparttocentry{%
  \doforeachtocfile{%
    \ifstr{\@currext}{toc}{}{%
        \addxcontentsline{\@currext}{partatlists}[{#1}]{#2}%
    }%
  }%
}{}{\PatchFailed}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  pagenumberbox=\@gobble,
  level=-1,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=0pt,
  dynnumwidth
]{part}{partatlists}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\part{Part One}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\captionof{figure}{My first figure}
\captionof{figure}{My second figure}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\captionof{figure}{A figure in Chapter Two}
\part{Part Two}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\captionof{figure}{My next figure}
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\addpart{Unnumbered Part}
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\captionof{figure}{My last figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! The second solution is more compact, and - imho - better. Two more clarifications: is it possible to remove page numbers on part titles lines (here `3`, `9` and `15`)? How to not include part titles if there is no figure within this part? (I do understand this might be a bit complex, since the `listof=chapterentry` option does not implement it -- i.e. all chapters, even empty, are listed)

Comment: I have added an example with a new style for the part entries in the lists to show how you can remove the page numbers. For the second question in your comment you can find a [suggestion for chapters on the KOMA-Script website](http://www.komascript.de/comment/5070#comment-5070). Maybe you can adapt this for parts.

Comment: *Thank you.* The link is really interesting. Ich soll ja mein Deutsch wieder üben, aber nicht, dass mir das missfällt ! I should have a look at KOMA-Script website more often!